# My app was removed from sale, how do I re-enlist it?

Tags: app-store

A co-worker removed our app from purchase due to a bug in it.

The new version is now reviewed and I want to re-enlist the app. I just can't find *how*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the **Status History** of your app, it will say for the latest version: **Developer Removed From Sale***

With the footnote pointing out:

> *This status indicates that the app has been removed from sale in all App Stores worldwide. To resume selling this app, go to the Rights and Pricing page and select at least one App Store where it will be sold.

1. Go to the app overview, and select **Rights and Pricing**:

   [image]
2. Then click the **Select all** button or make a more specific selection in the matrix below.

   [image]